# Data loss. How is it used in different ways

Tags: meaning, etymology

When a harddisk fails there can be data loss.
Which I understand.

But when the network gets hacked and hackers obtain creditcard details they also say it's a data loss.

But in the last case the data is not lost, only duplicated and in the wrong hands, why is it also called a loss?

Comment: The latter is usually called "data *theft*".

Answer (score 1):

> But in the last case the data is not lost, only duplicated and in the wrong hands, why is it also called a loss?

Because sometimes native speakers use English poorly.  And maybe never so often as when talking about networked computers or speaking on behalf of corporations, or, worst of all, both.

The real "loss" in that sort of "data loss" is **loss of control over the data**.  The pillaged company lost dominion over who gets access to what on their servers.

But what their customers and the press in general want to know is "what did they make off with?" and "who was impacted by the theft?"  The audience for such information is less concerned with the effect on the servers or the servers' owners than they are about their own data which was on those servers.  So the discussion is about the data, not the servers.  "Loss of control of the data" becomes, inaccurately, "data loss".

**Stolen** would be an excellent word to describe such data.  But I cynically suspect corporate communications professionals would prefer to use the word **lost** (and **loss**) because it sounds less bad (I am imagining they imagine) to imply "data was lost" rather than to imply "we were robbed", and that is shaping the choice of words in official announcements.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, the data/servers/network is compromised by the hackers.
The expected action would be to resend/reload/restore/recreate the data.
In other words the data is lost (at least for a specific time frame).

Answer (score 0):

In the same way some companies refer to software piracy as 'theft'.

It's not the physical 1's and 0's inside the machine that have been taken away, it's the *information* that wasn't supposed to leave the system that's been removed. My credit card data is protected by software security because I don't want it to be made public, if the security fails to do that then I have *lost* the data from the system because it was supposed to be kept inside. What good is to me if I have a credit card number that everyone knows locked away under protection?